# Перенос слова "здравствуйте"

Tags: перенос

Как правильно перенести слово **здравствуйте**?

Comment: Это был приказ? Или, может, Вы все-таки по-человечески напишите? И, кстати, "здравствуйте" тут берется в кавычки.

Comment: Да, тут встречаются и приказы(

Answer (score 1):

Здрав-ствуйте, здравствуй-те.